# Unable to use Ripple emulator

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build, ripple, rippledrawable

I am new to Ripple..My Problem is When I am importing a new project and trying to use ripple in that I am getting the following error in command prompt:

```
INFO: Server instance running on:http://localhost:4400
INFO: CORS XHR Proxy Service on: http://localhost:4400/ripple/xhr_proxy
INFO:JSONP XHR Proxy Service on: http://localhost:4400/ripple/jsonp_xhr_proxy
INFO: Could not find cordova as a local module.Expecting to find it installed Globally
```

I am using Ripple through Command Line.When I am creating a new project in Command Line ,I am able to use Ripple but when I am  trying to import a new project in new workspace and trying to use ripple I am getting the the above error message..Please suggest what to do..
Please Help....